# Talk Around vs Reverse

Tags: repeater, anytone

I thought that "Talk Around" and "Reverse" were two ways of referring to the same thing: swapping a channel's transmit and receive frequencies so that one could e.g. listen for other stations trying to reach a downed repeater. However, my Anytone radios expose both "Talk Around" and "Reverse" as options. What makes them different?

Edit: Adding image from manual "describing" them:

[image]

Comment: What model or models of radio do you have?

Comment: This is the Anytone D878UV and D578UV Pro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Talkaround: Transmitting and receiving on the repeater output frequency.  Thus, you "talk around" the repeater directly with the other station. (Same as simplex).  Both stations in a conversation can do this.

Reverse: Switching transmit and receive frequencies.  Thus, you can talk directly to another station that is still on the repeater's frequency.  But if both stations reverse, then they can not hear each other.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Nice first answer!